# How to use JSDoc with generic typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, lint, jsdoc

What is the best way to use JSDoc for generic typescript functions.
Below is something I tried, but I guess there's a best way to do it, because there is an information saying **`JSDoc types may be moved to TypeScript types.ts(80004)`**

I clicked the "quick fix", but that messed up the function.

```
/**
 * @description  execute in parallel promises by chunks
 * @type <ReturnType> : the type of data to be returned
 * @param arrayPromises : the array of promises to execute
 * @param chunks : the value of chunks
 * @returns : an array of returnType
 */
const runPromisesInParallelbyChunks = async <ReturnType>(
    arrayPromises: Array<() => Promise<ReturnType>>,
    chunks: number
): Promise<ReturnType[]> => {
    const result: ReturnType[] = [];
    let resu: ReturnType[] = [];
    let cnt: number = 0;
    const chain = async (
        shrinkArray: Array<() => Promise<ReturnType>>
    ): Promise<ReturnType> => {
        if (!shrinkArray.length) {
            return new Promise<ReturnType>(resolve => resolve());
        }
        // console.log(shrinkArray.length);
        const i: number = cnt++;
        const res: ReturnType = await shrinkArray.shift()!();
        await delayExecution(100);
        // SAVE RESULT OF THE EXECUTION OF THE FUNCTION
        result[i] = res;
        return chain(shrinkArray);
    };
    const arrChains: Array<Promise<ReturnType>> = [];
    while (chunks-- > 0 && arrayPromises.length > 0) {
        arrChains.push(chain(arrayPromises));
    }
    // RESULT IS AN ARRAY OF THE RESULT OF EACH PROMISE
    resu = await Promise.all(arrChains).then(() => result);

    return resu;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the @type doesn't need to be there. I had types in my @params and once I took those out, I stopped getting this.

```
@param {string} containerName - Name of the container. 
public async exampleFunc(containerName: string)
```

to

```
@param containerName - Name of the container.
public async exampleFunc(containerName: string)
```

https://dev.to/kamranayub/why-you-don-t-need-types-in-jsdoc-when-documenting-typescript-1pb0